# JREs from different vendors on the same system

Tags: package-management, java, jre

In various tutorials, it is said, that you should remove existing JRE/JDK before installing new one (e.g. remove OpenJDK before installing the one from Oracle).
Is it really necessary? I remember having 2 JREs at one point, being able to choose in my IDE which to run program on.

Don't remember to have any conflicts, what's the chance of having any?

Answer (score 11):

You can install multiple JRE/JDK at a time. You just need to configure which one to use by using **update-alternatives**

**sudo update-alternatives --config java**

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status

---

0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java         1061      auto mode

1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java         1061      manual mode

* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1

Similarly, you can configure your JDK with

**sudo update-alternatives --config javac**

Comment: it worked like a charm

Comment: Bravo my friend, it works ;)