# How to find my current JAVA_HOME in ubuntu?

Tags: java, home-directory

How to find my current JAVA_HOME in ubuntu? I have to set java_home path when installing maven.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

To display `JAVA_HOME` variable path, type in terminal:

```bsh
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

**If nothing appears** then set it with this:

```bsh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

This will differ according to your JDK type and version.

For displaying it again, follow the first command.

Follow [JREs from different vendors on the same system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303672/jres-from-different-vendors-on-the-same-system/458796#458796), for using different JDK's or switch between JDK's.

Comment: It gives "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun". But I have installed java 7. When I check it using "java -version" it gives java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: then execute second command for setting JAVA_HOME variable. NOTE:`JAVA_HOME doesn't make jdk default, it just makes JAVA_HOME variable set to a path & if you want to use different jdk installed on same machine then check my answer, I have edited it.`

Comment: you should set it in /etc/environment

Comment: @Jax-L But now when I give echo JAVA_HOME it just displays as "JAVA_HOME". The path I gave is not displaying...???

Comment: read it properly its `echo $JAVA_HOME`. You forgot dollar($) sign.

Comment: @otakun85 setting in etc/environment does the same thing done by export command no?

Comment: export works only until you restart. Or you add export to the .bashrc login script. But the correct way to set such environment variables is in /etc/environment

Comment: no, they aren't same, but can also set by editing `/etc/environment` file. Yes, they are same until you exit your session. Better set it in `/etc/environment`, you will find JAVA_HOME on reboot

Comment: so does setting in etc/environment makes it permanent???

Answer (score 43):

If you have JDK 1.6 (corresponding to Java 6) or a newer version installed, you should have a program named `jrunscript` in your `PATH`.  You can use this to find the corresponding `JAVA_HOME`. Example:

```
$ jrunscript -e 'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));'
/opt/local/jdk1.7.0_76/jre
```

You could set the environment variable like this:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME="$(jrunscript -e 'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));')"
```

Note that the JRE doesn't include `jrunscript`, so this will only work if you install the JDK, not just the JRE.

Comment: That was a lot to go through to figure out i needed to go one directory deeper, but thanks.

Answer (score 28):

Another portable options is to extract the absolute path of the JRE from `java`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`type -p java|xargs readlink -f|xargs dirname|xargs dirname`
```

The absolute `java` path is passed to `dirname` twice to remove `/bin/java` from the end. Complete extraction of the directory goes as follows:

```
$ type -p java
/usr/bin/java

$ readlink -f /usr/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java

$ dirname /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/

$ dirname /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
```

Comment: one can use `type -p javac|xargs readlink -f|xargs dirname|xargs dirname` (without the export part) to know the directory without setting it.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Brilliant answer!

Comment: Here there is no `javac`. Worked with `java`

Comment: @alanjds good point. Switched the answer from `javac` to `java`. `javac` is only available in JDK.

Answer (score 12):

Just run a command

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

It will give something like

```
Es gibt nur eine Alternative in Link-Gruppe java (die /usr/bin/java bereitstellt): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

From this you have /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/ as java home. You may now export it to JAVA_HOME variable

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
```

Now echo $JAVA_HOME show it

Answer (score 9):

To take into account the update-alternatives mechanism:

```
$ update-alternatives --query java | grep 'Value: ' | grep -o '/.*/jre'
```

You could set the environment variable like this:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME="$(update-alternatives --query java | grep 'Value: ' | grep -o '/.*/jre')"
```

Comment: This doesn't quite give the JAVA_HOME as it will still have the trailing `/jre`. You might try `export JAVA_HOME="$(update-alternatives --query java | grep 'Value: ' | sed -e 's/Value: //;s?/jre/bin/java??;')"`

Answer (score 3):

I use this in Ubuntu LTS (14.04 / 16.04):

```
[ -L /etc/alternatives/java ] && 
  export JAVA_HOME="$(readlink -f /etc/alternatives/java | sed -e 's/\/jre\/bin\/java$//')"
```

Answer (score 3):

For Java 9 and later:

This answer https://askubuntu.com/a/657468/963 uses the enclosed Nashorn JavaScript engine Nashorn to print out the `java.home` system property.   Nashorn is being deprecated so an alternative is to use `jshell` introduced in Java 9.

```
echo 'System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));' | jshell  -
```

which on my Ubuntu 18.10 system prints out:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Java environment variables

The PPA also contains a package to automatically set Java environment variables, just run command:

```
sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
```

From this article:
[Install Oracle Java 8 / 9 in Ubuntu 16.04, Linux Mint 18](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/31/install-oracle-java-8-9-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18/)

Answer (score 1):

to get `JAVA_HOME`:

```
update-alternatives --query java | grep 'Value: ' | sed 's/Value: \(.*\)\/bin\/java/\1/'

## e.g. returns  </opt/Oracle_Java/jre1.8.0_202> 
## if            </etc/alternatives/java>  points to 
##               </opt/Oracle_Java/jre1.8.0_202/bin/java>
```

to set `JAVA_HOME`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(update-alternatives --query java | grep 'Value: ' | sed 's/Value: \(.*\)\/bin\/java/\1/')"
```

Comment: You can use a different separation character for *sed* expressions to make it simpler to read, for example an arobase : `... | sed 's@Value: \(.*\)/bin/java@\1@'` (so you don't need to escape the slashes of the path). But it looks unusual for newcomers.

Comment: @Lenormju good point and thx for reminding, but with the `@` it looks really weird to me and I would have to visually solve one more problem of already complicated stuff as you mentioned similarly. but `... | sed 's|Value: \(.*\)/bin/java|\1|'` could be something I personally would choose (if it works - I did not test it) if it would seem more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

For versions that support `-XshowSettings:properties`:

While `alternatives` may remain popular I mostly use [jenv](https://www.jenv.be) and occasionally [sdkman](https://sdkman.io), which all introduce a level of indirection; if you are happy to ask `java` itself:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version |& grep -Po '(?<=java.home = )(.*)'
```

This is not available in Java 6:

```
docker run --rm openjdk:6 java -XshowSettings:properties -version
Unrecognized option: -XshowSettings:properties
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

It is available since Java 7:

```
 dk run --rm openjdk:7 bash -c "java -XshowSettings:properties -version |& grep -Po '(?<=java.home = |java.home=)(.*)'"
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf/jre
```