# Minecraft confusion?

Tags: java, launcher, kde, games, minecraft

So I bought mine craft and I looked on you tube found how to do it and did it only there was a problem.
I ran the launcher hit play and then it pops up the launcher again and says:
something about exit code 1 blah blah blah and ignoring visibility rule and showing launcher do to a game crash.... I've tried java 7 and 6 but neither of them worked so is there anything else that will help?

Comment: Please post some screenshots.

Comment: Can you please put the log that the launcher has? You should be able to go to the Launcher Logs tab, right click it, select copy all text, then paste it here. It gives us more information on what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to launch minecraft thru command line?  The command to do this is:

```
java -jar 'your minecraft program with it's path'
```

(You can type `java -jar` then drag and drop the minecraft program in the terminal windows, to get the path to automatically be entered)

---

You can also try `minetest` which is an open source alternative to minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to launch a minecraft server or the minecraft client?

If **Server**

Have you launched the application with a different user on console compared to the user you are logged on right now ? If so, you can try to start the server without gui `java -jar minecraft-server.jar nogui`, and controle your server only via console.

If **Client**

Maybe your java installation wasn't recognized by minecraft. Have you ensured, that your JRE_HOME and/or JAVA_HOME is set after installation? If not, you can find hints [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459900/how-to-find-my-current-java-home-in-ubuntu) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java)